# Is there a complete connectome of a cortical minicolumn?

Tags: neuroscience, brain

I know that there are [projects](http://www.humanconnectomeproject.org) that try to map brain connectivity. Given that a cortical microcolumn has only around a hundred neurons I wonder whether there is a dataset available with the complete connectivity of just a single [minicolumn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortical_minicolumn) of the neocortex. Doesn't have to be human.

I posed this question on [cognitive science stackexchange](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/16090/is-there-a-complete-connectome-of-a-minicolumn-of-the-neocortex) already, but it doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has cross-posted to cogsci.se and has an answer there: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/16090/is-there-a-complete-connectome-of-a-minicolumn-of-the-neocortex

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the first place to look would be the [Allen Brain Atlas](http://connectivity.brain-map.org/)
 (for mice, [this](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v508/n7495/abs/nature13186.html) is a paper about it), and also [this paper].(https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4169118/)